# Mark email as read with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a big amateur in Google App Script.

Have this script runing ok but need to implement one more fuction. 
Now i need this:
**The emails read by the script I need to be marked as read**

I have tried to integrate several options but without positive result.

Could anyone help me to implement it in the script itself

```
function processInboxToSheet() {
  //var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  // Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!
  var start = 0;
  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1d AND is:unread AND label:eur OR label:desc",0,100); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();

    // implement your own parsing rule inside
    if (content) {
      var tmp;
      tmp = content.match(/\b([A-B\d][A-B\d]{4})\b/);
      var cod = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      tmp = content.match(/\b(\d+[R])/);
      var prom = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      tmp = content.match(/\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)\b/);
      var exp = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      sheet.appendRow([cod, prom, exp]);

      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }


  }
};
```

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. Have you looked into the `.markRead()` method?

Comment: You can mark a message as read via [GmailMessage.markRead()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#markread) or a thread via [GmailThread.markRead()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#markread). If you have problems doing this please provide more details on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for response guys. Only have the code I paste in the first message. I looked in the **.markRead()** but not working for me in my code. I am a big amateur in this, sorry.    @lamblichus What i wish to achieve is "simple" (but for me very hard). The script have in the first message parse email data for some emails, I just need that after analyzing the messages, mark them as read in gmail. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to mark as read the first message in each of the threads. To do that, you have to use [markRead()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#markread).

Now, this is a method that corresponds to the [GmailMessage class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message). Hence, you need to call this method from an instance of this class. Right now, in your code, you have the variable `messages` which is an array of the messages in a thread, not a message. To access the individual messages, you have to specify an index of the array. The first message in the thread corresponds to `message[0]`, so that's where you have to use `markRead`.

So the only thing you would need to do is adding the following line of code anywhere inside the `for` loop and after you have defined `messages`:

```js
messages[0].markRead();
```

(If you only want to mark the message as read if the message has body content, you would have to add the line above inside the `if` block.)

Also, if you wanted to mark the thread as read instead (a GmailThread also has a [markRead method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#markread), you could at this line of code at the beginning of the `for` loop:

```js
threads[i].markRead();
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Ouuuuu mama !!   @Iamblichus many, many thanks! working perfect!

Comment: @Markusen you're most welcome. Also, please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: I created a new question by implementing your answer and related to this script. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751806/read-all-message-in-gmail-label-with-google-app-script)
You would be so kind to help me in same condition, read all emails, no only the first message in the threads? Thanks!