# Read all message in Gmail Label with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a big amateur in Google App Script.

Rescued this script that works for me but not correctly.
Now only read and phsarse info for the first message of the thread not all the messages.

I need to read,check, and pharse **all messages** of a label, not only the first of the thread.
I need that the script read and pharse all the individual messages 
located on a tag.
Then marks all as read.

Someone could help me and change the code to do this?
I review Google APP Script manual and I've tried different things but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

````
  //var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  // Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!
  var start = 0;
  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1d AND is:unread AND label:eur OR label:desc",0,100); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();
    messages[0].markRead();
    // implement your own parsing rule inside
    if (content) {
      var tmp;
      tmp = content.match(/\b([A-B\d][A-B\d]{4})\b/);
      var cod = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      tmp = content.match(/\b(\d+[R])/);
      var prom = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      tmp = content.match(/\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)\b/);
      var exp = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Error';

      sheet.appendRow([cod, prom, exp]);

      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }


  }
}; ```
````

Answer (score 1):

In order to mark messages as read, you have to iterate messages of each thread.

You are only getting the first message of the thread, so you have to replace

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

  var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();
  messages[0].markRead();

  .....
```

to something like this:

```
function readMails (){

  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1d AND is:unread AND label:eur OR label:desc",0,100);

  //Iterate threads
  for (var i=0; i < threads.length; i++){

    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    //Iterate messages of each thread
    for (var k=0; k < messages.length; k++){
      var content = messages[k].getPlainBody();
      messages[k].markRead();

      .....
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan! I tried to implement it in the code but not in google sheet it doesn't show me any results. 
This is how I inserted it in the main code. there is something wrong? https://www.codepile.net/pile/D2OG702E

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of threads already, you can use the `markThreadsRead` method to mark them all read in one go.

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1d AND is:unread AND label:eur OR label:desc",0,100); 
GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
```

Alternatively, you can process individual messages in the thread as below:

```
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
messages.forEach(function(message) {
  message.markRead();
  // processs the message here and save to sheets
})
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. Not understand very well where I need to put your "alternatively code to process individual messages. You can send me a link with your complete code integrated in the main one? Thank you. I have tried as follows but it has not worked for me. Mark all message read, but only pharse info to sheet for one in loop: https://www.codepile.net/pile/lQDZy73z